# Mongoid history - performance issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am trying to version documents in MongoDB, using mongoid and mongoid-history gems. Unfortunately I encountered performance issue.

When I fetch collection of documents and I want to fetch specific version for each entry, then every call of method: `entry.history_tracks` causes invoke of 1 database query to the collection of history tracks. So when I have a collection of 100 entries, I get 1+100 database queries.

Is there any easy way to fix this problem? I tried `cache` method but it doesn't solve the problem, since each query is different.

Comment: what does your document look like?

Comment: Let's assume that it's a simple document with 2 string fields: title and content. I would like to track it's creation, update and deletion.

Comment: I don't know how mongoid-history works, but why doesn't it embeds the history of the document inside the entry itself? Or maybe create a different model like EntryHistory that would includes the whole history of the object, not store them separately.

Comment: If you open mongoid-history issues list you will find that it's inconsistent with their assumptions to store entire history in the document: https://github.com/aq1018/mongoid-history/issues/60


Storing history of the whole collection inside one document might cause scalability problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I gave up and finished with two mongo collections, one containing published entries, and one containing current entries (drafts). Every time when I want to publish something, these two collections are synced in very smart way. Thank you for your anwsers!